# how to install ubuntu from internal ssd

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, ssd

I have a laptop that has a 500GB HDD, and a 24GB SSD. I currently have ubuntu 16.04 installed on the HDD. I want to do a complete reinstallation of ubuntu, and reinstall a new copy of ubuntu over the old one.

Instead of using a USB flash drive to do this, I want to use my internal SSD. I tried the usual method for using a flash drive, and i got the ISO image onto the SSD, but I cant boot from it, or even see it in the boot menu. I tried changing the boot order, but my BIOS didn't even recognize the SSD.

How can I install ubuntu using an internal SSD?

Comment: There can be two kinds of problems: 1. Boot from the internal SSD. This depends on the computer's UEFI/BIOS system. Maybe you can find a temporary boot menu. Otherwise you must change the settings to make the computer boot from the SSD; 2. Make the SSD bootable. I do that often (with my SSD) using [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Comment: You can customize grub to boot from an iso and install that way as long as the iso is on a different physical device from where you are installing.  If that method will work for you, comment and I'll write an answer.

Comment: It is also possible, that the computer cannot boot from the internal SSD. What computer is it? **Please specify the brand name and model of the computer**.

Comment: If you are using an OS that uses grub just add a menuentry to loop mount the ISO on the SSD. Reboot and then install Ubuntu to the HDD. Let me know if you want a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the Ubuntu ISO at the root of the SSD.

Modify the /boot/grub/grub.cfg as shown:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Ubuntu-18.04 64-bit ISO" {
    set root=(hd0,1)
    set isofile="/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile splash --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

(hd0,1) assumes root is sda1.
If your grub is located on the HDD and not the SSD you will need to give the correct path to the ISO file, set root=(hd?,?).